# Complex Mysql query grouping columns

Tags: mysql

[image: Table]

I have a table like above. I need out like below Using `Mysql` query.

[image: Output]

Comment: I tried `SELECT emp_name,count(attendance) FROM `test`where attendance='present' GROUP by emp_name`. but this is not i want.

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times here is SO. Please spend some time researching the site for relevant answers before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the result by using conditional aggregate,

```
SELECT EMP_NAME,
       SUM(attendance = 'Present')  AS `No of Present`,
       SUM(attendance = 'Absent')  AS `No of Absent`
FROM tableName
GROUP BY EMP_NAME
```